# Difference between cloned object and hardcoded HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Scenario is to copy `#first` inside `#test`, below are the 2 scenarios of implementing it and which is the best way of implementation and why?

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">1</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div>--------------</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY1:**

```
var cloner = $('.first').clone().prop({
    'class': 'changed_first'
});
$('.test').append(cloner)
$('.changed_first > .second').attr('class', 'changed_second');
$('.changed_first > .second').html('2');
```

Detour question on JQUERY1: Is there a possibility in the clone method to change the properties of inner elements?

**JQUERY2:**

```
$('.test').append('<div class="changed_first"><div class="changed_second">2</div></div>');
```

Comment: Asking for 'the best' method is a very vague term that needs more defining, best in terms of speed, or shortest code, or...? I haven't tested it, but I would assume that the second method is by far the quickest as you only make one DOM access call. It's not very maintenance friendly though.

Comment: If you modify the clone before you insert, you get away with just modifying the DOM once, and `cloneNode` is generally quite fast

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vodf2ebs/

Comment: Thanks. it helped me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 1st method of using clone will be a good one.

And yes you can manipulate the cloned elements before you bind it to dom.

If you want to access any id or class to cloned element before you bind if to anywhere, you can do like

```
var cloner = $('.first').clone().prop({
    'class': 'changed_first'
});

cloner.find('#id').css('something','css-value');
var data_id = cloner.find('.class').attr('data-bind');
```

Comment: Because if you will go with 2nd method, you can not write more jQuery until you will append the generated content with some existing elements of DOM.
While with clonned, as I said, You can give any css or you can even modify the elements before you put it in HTML code. In short, you can manipulate that `cloner` variable before you attach it anywhere.

Comment: Your welcome @yogi. Can I have UP vote to my answer ?